# DNS records in subdomain would override records in parent?

Tags: dns

Before today, I think one domain can be setup only one DNS provider and I did it so, one colleague told me he setup some NS records for a subdomain and got some issues.

I registered domain at Godaddy and modified NS servers to DNSPod (a DNS service provider), and I added some NS records for a subdomain, and pointed it to Azure DNS zone, e.g. `sec.example.com`.

I could add `a.sec.example.com` and `b.sec.example.com` records on both sides, which records should be used?

I tested the records under Azure DNS zone will be returned to `dig`, I'm not sure is there a standard (RFCxxxx) or a client specified rule?

Is it possible return the records under DNSPod ? if the DNS request first hit DNSPod, it could return directly.